# IIS Express - temporarily impersonate the authenticated user

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-express

According to this document:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

I've set the following in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

And have also set this in the applicationhost.config for IIS Express 7.5

```
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />

<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add value="Negotiate" />
    <add value="NTLM" />
  </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

But System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity still always equals the Windows identity of the authenticated user, i.e. not the account that IISExpress.exe is running under (my dev account).

To be clear, I'm logged-in as Account A and IIS Express runs as Account A, but I call my web service using Account B (setting the Credentials on HttpWebRequest) but the server-side code runs as Account B, i.e. the thread has this id and I can access network resources.

I'd like execution to occur as Account A (and on the prod server, as a service account) and only impersonate when I want it to.

Am I doing something wrong or is this area not perfectly implemented in IISX?

Thanks

Luke

## Update 1

So, I thought I figured-out what was going on; see my answer below. The problem is that it seems to be working in reverse!

```
string n1 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;    // Runtime account.
string n2 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;         // Calling account.

var winId = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
try
{
    bool b = System.IO.File.Exists(@"d:\p\p.txt");    // true (!)

    using (ctx = winId.Impersonate())
    {
        // Now impersonating. Access (local) resources using the identity of the authenticated user.

        n1 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;   // Calling account.
        n2 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;        // Calling account.

        b = System.IO.File.Exists(@"d:\p\p.txt");     // false (!)
    }
...
```

The folder d:\p is set to only allow the calling account access, which is fine when tested in DOS but from my web service, it has access and I expect this is because the thread has the caller's security context, BEFORE I've begun impersonating!

Weirder still, when I do impersonate, I suddenly lose access to it!

I'm going to create a test project on a proper IIS 7.5 server and see if this is a bug in IIS Express.

## Update 2

The problem with the Exists test has been half-solved. I removed rights to the folder but the file itself still had some rights, and the way .NET accesses files without traversing the folder means it could still access it.

Now I get

```
b == false // as expected.
...
b == false // unexpected, after impersonation I should be able to see this file.
```

I'd expect impersonation to give me access, it doesn't.

## Update 3

I've given up. Impersonation doesn't work and I can only assume its a network policy or some undiscoverable hidden setting.

Comment: That MSDN document is for an old version of IIS. Have you followed the steps at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708(v=ws.10) ?

Comment: Interestingly, the original document suggests that I should disable impersonation, which it is, and this makes sense because I just need the Windows Id of the caller so I can call Impersonate with it when I need.

Comment: In another ASMX service I wrote some years ago, I've set the impersonation = true and supplied some service account creds, which makes me wonder if I encountered the same problem back then!

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Sort of.

```
string n1 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string n2 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

n1 = the process identity
n2 = the caller's identity

The thread's security context has the caller's identity, which I didn't expect. I thought the thread would have the context of the process flowed to it, but this is clearly not how it works.

I now have an interesting situation that when I call .Impersonate on the callers WindowsIdentity, I still can't access a local file permissioned for the calling account, but I'll work that out and update my answer.

**SEE UPDATE IN QUESTION**